# VS 2022 - Rebuild Error - NSwag - openapi2csclient - exited with code -1

Tags: visual-studio-2022, nswag

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.6.5), the nuget package for  NSwag.ApiDescription.Client (version 13.19.0).

When try to Rebuild, its is getting this error:

```
The command ""x\packages_rep\nswag.msbuild\13.0.5\build\../tools/Win/NSwag.exe" openapi2csclient /className:ServiceClient /namespace:MyService /input:x\swagger.json /output:obj\swaggerClient.cs " exited with code -1.
```

Where `x` above is my local web project path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause in my case was the whitespaces in the path to the project.

We need to fix in the file:

```
{MyProject}\packages_rep\nswag.apidescription.client\13.0.5\build\NSwag.ApiDescription.Client.targets
```

You will find line # 21 similar to this:

```
 <Command>%(Command) /input:%(FullPath) /output:%(OutputPath) %(Options)</Command>
```

To make swagger work with whitespaces, change this line by adding double quotes around the `path`:

```
 <Command>%(Command) /input:"%(FullPath)" /output:"%(OutputPath)" %(Options)</Command>
```

My project works fine after this fix.